# can we make the if's more generic?

Tags: javascript

I am looking to reduce the lines here. can we have it in a more generic way ?

```
if ((method === "T" || method === "M") && !number) {
    alerts.error("Please input phone number")
    return;
}
if (method === "E" && !email) {
    alerts.error("Please input Email")
    return;
}
```

Comment: what do you call generic?

Comment: hmm.reduce the lines in this case ,

Comment: Reducing the number of lines != generic. In fact, reducing the number of lines often requires you to be incredibly specific and can massively over complicate your code. I would say it is fine as is.

Comment: reducing lines is not a good goal, work to make your code self-documenting and human readable, even if you have to add lines... Also, when you post a question to StackOverflow you need to demonstrate what you have already tried to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: Not sure what the benefit would be.

Comment: I don't see any reason to reduce number of lines here. You could probably put `return` and `alerts.error()` in one line like `return alerts.error()`.

Comment: As other people have mentioned, you're probably better off leaving it as is. If you wanted to break it down logically, you could turn code into a switch statement. It might not be "Shorter" but it might make your logic more "Generic".

Comment: @ZacharyOldham makes sense !

Comment: `(["T", "M"].includes(method) && !number)`

Comment: @mruanova I rolled back the title because this is equally unrelated to [tag:html].

Comment: Tried to turn it into two ternaries but the code was getting way too messy

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is a switch/case statement.

Normally, you would do something like this:

```
switch(method) {
  case 'T':
  case 'M':
    alerts.error('Please input phone number');
    break;

  case 'E':
    alerts.error('Please input e-mail');
    break;
}
```

Since you have additional conditions to check, it's not uncommon to flip the switch/case around to check booleans:

```
switch(true) {
  case (method === 'T' || method === 'M') && !number):
  // etc.
}
```

Comment: Was thinking something similar, switch(true) is pretty ugly tbh but it get's the job done. I wonder if there's some architecture that has a concept of nested switch statements (For switching on method & number simultaneously)

Comment: @ZakkDiaz There's nothing ugly about `switch(true)` *if* it communicates what's actually happening.  This is a rare case, but it does come in handy from time to time.

Comment: Indeed it is a rare case, self descriptive code always wins. I think what's exceptionally nice about this is you can take advantage of the fall-through in the truthy & falsy case

Comment: The problem with `switch(true)` is that it generally fails to communicate what's actually happening. In several other languages that would not even be a syntactically valid `case`, so it's just confusing. **edit** oh, and don't even get me started on implicit fall-through...

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Sometimes, it *does* communicate what is happening.  And, this is JavaScript, not some other language.  By all means, if you're working on a team of people who don't generally use JavaScript, don't use it.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you can clean up code like this to increase readability. One way is by using boolean variables to better describe your conditionals.

```
isNumber = (method === "T" || method === "M") && !number
isEmail = method === "E" && !email

if (isNumber) {
    alerts.error("Please input phone number")
    return;
}
if (isEmail) {
    alerts.error("Please input Email")
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expected result, use if condition within main if for alert

```
if (((method === "T" || method === "M") && !number) || ((method === "E" && !email))) {    
    method === 'E'? alerts.error("Please input Email") : alerts.error("Please input phone number")
    return;
}
```

working code sample

```js
function test(){
  method = 'E';
  email = null;
  number = null;

if (((method === "T" || method === "M") && !number) || ((method === "E" && !email))) {    
    method === 'E'? alert("Please input Email") : alert("Please input phone number")
    return;
}
}

test()
```

Comment: This just made everything more complex! It's bundled up nicely but now you have to decrypt a one-liner

Comment: Agree @ZakkDiaz, splitting those if conditions would be more readable , as that if conditions mainly handles method type(T,M,E) , this one liner also readable but gets complicated if there are more methods

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the question is about aesthetics. If so then "match" idiom may work:

```
var err = method === "T" && !number ? "Please input phone number" 
        : method === "M" && !number ? "Please input phone number" 
        : method === "E" && !email ? "Please input Email" 
        : null;

if(err) return alerts.error(err);
```